# Strange behavior when a function declared as noexcept throws an exception in its default argument

Tags: c++, exception, language-lawyer, noexcept

Here is an example about my question:

```
struct B {
    B(B&&, int = (throw 0, 0)) noexcept {}
};
```

I know this is a very strange piece of code. It is just used to illustrate the problem. The move constructor of `B` has a `noexcept` specifier, while it has a default argument which throws an exception.

If I use the `noexcept` operator to test the move constructor, it will return `false`. But if I provide the second argument, it will then return 'true' (both on GCC and Clang):

```
noexcept( B(std::declval<B>()) );    // false
noexcept( B(std::declval<B>(), 1) ); // true
```

Then I added class `D`, which inherits from `B` and does not provide a move constructor.

```
struct D : public B { };
```

And I tested class `D`:

```
noexcept( D(std::declval<D>()) );  // true
```

I have read the standard and I think that according to the standard, `noexcept( D(std::declval<D>()) )` should return `false`.

Now I try to analyze the results according to the standard.

According to [[expr.unary.noexcept]](https://eel.is/c++draft/expr.unary.noexcept#3):

> The result of the `noexcept` operator is `true` unless **the expression is potentially-throwing** ([except.spec]).

So now we need to judge whether the expression `B(std::declval<B>())` is **potentially-throwing**.

According to [[except.spec]](https://eel.is/c++draft/except.spec#6):

> An expression *E* is potentially-throwing if
>
> - *E* is a function call whose ..., with a **potentially-throwing exception specification**, or
> - *E* implicitly invokes a function (such as ...) that has a **potentially-throwing exception specification**, or
> - *E* is a throw-expression, or
> - *E* is a `dynamic_cast` expression ...
> - *E* is a `typeid` expression ...
> - any of the **immediate subexpressions** of *E* is potentially-throwing.

In my example, the expression calls the move constructor of `B` which is `noexcept`, so it does not belong to the first two cases. Obviously, it does not belong to the next three situations.

The definition of *immediate subexpressions* is in [[intro.execution]](https://eel.is/c++draft/intro.execution#3):

> The *immediate subexpressions* of an expression *E* are
>
> - the constituent expressions of *E*'s operands ([expr.prop]),
> - any function call that *E* implicitly invokes,
> - if *E* is lambda-expression, ...
> - if *E* is a function call or implicitly invokes a function, the constituent expressions of each **default argument**([dcl.fct.default]) **used in the call**, or
> - if *E* creates an aggregate object ...

According to the standard, the default argument `(throw 0, 0)` is the *immediate subexpression* of `B(std::declval<B>())`, but not the *immediate subexpression* of `B(std::declval<B>(), 1)`, and `throw 0` is the *immediate subexpression* of `(throw 0, 0)`, which is a potentially-throwing expression. So `(throw 0, 0)` and `B(std::declval<B>())` are also potentially-throwing expressions. It is true that `noexcept( B(std::declval<B>()) )` returns `false` and `noexcept( B(std::declval<B>(), 1) )` returns `true`.

But I am confused about the last example. Why `noexcept( D(std::declval<D>()) )` returns `true`? `D(std::declval<D>())` will implicitly invokes the move constructor of `B`, which satisfies the second requirement of *immediate subexpression*. So it should also satisfy the requirement of *potentially-throwing* transitively. But the result is just the opposite.

So is my explanation of the reasons for the first two results correct? And what is the reason for the third result?

---

Edit:

There is a similar example in the standard. In [[except.spec]](https://eel.is/c++draft/except.spec#12):

```
struct A {
  A(int = (A(5), 0)) noexcept;
  A(const A&) noexcept;
  A(A&&) noexcept;
  ~A();
};
struct B {
  B() noexcept;
  B(const B&) = default;        // implicit exception specification is noexcept(true)
  B(B&&, int = (throw 42, 0)) noexcept;
  ~B() noexcept(false);
};
int n = 7;
struct D : public A, public B {
    int * p = new int[n];
    // D​::​D() potentially-throwing, as the new operator may throw bad_­alloc or bad_­array_­new_­length
    // D​::​D(const D&) non-throwing
    // D​::​D(D&&) potentially-throwing, as the default argument for B's constructor may throw
    // D​::​~D() potentially-throwing
};
```

All special member functions in `A` are `noexcept`, while the move constructor of `B` is potentially-throwing, and the destructor of `B` is `noexcept(false)`.

Will `D`'s move constructor be affected by `B`'s destructor? Probably not. Because `D`'s copy constructor is also affected by `B`'s destructor, but `D`'s copy constructor is not-throwing.

Besides, according to [[except.spec]](https://eel.is/c++draft/except.spec#note-2):

> Even though destructors for fully-constructed subobjects are invoked when an exception is thrown during the execution of a constructor ([except.ctor]), **their exception specifications do not contribute to the exception specification of the constructor**, because an exception thrown from such a destructor would call the function `std​::​terminate` rather than escape the constructor ([except.throw], [except.terminate]).

So the move constructor of `D` is truly affected by the move constructor of `B`.

Comment: To clarify, calling the move constructor of `D` does result in a throw.

Comment: "_Why `noexcept( D(std::declval<D>()) )` returns `true`?_" - Because you erroneously claimed that moving `B` can't throw. I suspect _undefined behavior_. Edit: [example](https://godbolt.org/z/c3EPM44vh) (remove `noexcept` and it'll catch the exception just fine instead of crashing)

Comment: @TedLyngmo Throwing from `noexcept` is defined to call `std::terminate` (or `std::unexpected` depending on the version of C++), it is not UB.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux Ah, thanks - yes, I do see the `std::terminate` call in the log I provided myself :-)

Comment: I always thought default arguments were evaluated in the context of the caller, not as part of the function. I would expect throwing while evaluating a default argument value would not be affected by the function being `noexcept`. Edit : On second thought, I guess either way the default argument in the context of the `noexcept` operator, so it makes sense that the result would also depend on default arguments.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux I call the move constructor of `D` in a `try` block with a `catch - all` clause, but it still called `std::terminate`. If I explicitly declare the move-ctor of `D` as `noexcept(false)`, the exception will be caught by the `catch -all` clause. So I think you are correct. The exception thrown from the default argument will be caught by the caller. Because the move-ctor of `D` is `noexcept`(and this is what i don't understand), the exception will be "caught" by `noexcept` in `D` and `std::terminate` will be invoked.

Comment: @Pluto `D::D(D&&)` will be `noexcept(false)` by default if you don't make an erroneous claim in `B::B(B&&, int = (throw 0, 0))` - which should be `noexcept(false)` - and it will be by default, if you don't explicitly set it to `noexcept(true)`

Comment: If I understand [except.spec#7](https://eel.is/c++draft/except.spec#7) correctly, `D(D&&)` should be `noexcept(false)`...

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux I also hope this is a compiler bug, because I can't find an error in my analysis of the standard. But `B(B&&, int = (throw 42, 0)) noexcept` is actually an example in the standard. I just simplified it.

Comment: @Pluto I think Jaro42d's link simplifies the analysis. It seems to me like *"the invocation of a constructor selected by overload resolution in the implicit definition of the constructor for class X to initialize a potentially constructed subobject"* is potentially throwing so `D(D&&)` should not be `noexcept` even if `B(B&&)` is `noexcept`. I think the compiler is taking a shortcut and only looking at if the subobject constructor itself is qualified as `noexcept`, not if invoking that constructor is `noexcept`.

Comment: @Jarod42 Yes, this also proves that `D(D&&)` should be `noexcept(false)`. Is this really a problem with the compiler? But why do GCC, Clang and MSVC all have the same result? Moreover, this example is simplified from the example in the standard.

Comment: "_if and only if any of the following constructs is potentially-throwing: ... the invocation of a constructor selected by overload resolution in the implicit definition of the constructor for class X to initialize a potentially constructed subobject_" - but, the subobject move constructor is not potentially throwing if declared as `B(B&&, int = (throw 0, 0)) noexcept` - the fact that it may throw anyway is not up to `D::D(D&&)` to analyze

Comment: @TedLyngmo: Even example from [except.spec#12](https://eel.is/c++draft/except.spec#12) states: "`// D​::​D(D&&) potentially-throwing, as the default argument for B's constructor may throw`".

Comment: @Jarod42 Indeed - I stand corrected. Utterly confused, but still :-)

Comment: @TedLyngmo I don't think `B(B&&)` is not potentially-throwing. *Potentially-throwing expression* and *potentially-throwing exception specification* are different. `B(B&&)` is marked with `noexcept`, it simply does not satisfy the latter. But it is still a *potentially-throwing expression*, because `noexcept(B(std::declval<B>()))` returns `false`.

Comment: @Pluto Yes, `B::B(B&&, int = ...)` is potentially throwing but when marked with `noexcept` it'll call `std::terminate` instead of throwing an exception. My belief (up until a few minutes ago) was that `D::D(D&&)` would make itself `noexcept` by default because of the `noexcept` in `B`.

Comment: @TedLyngmo I am so similar to you. Before I saw the strange example in the standard, I always thought that the `noexcept` of the move constructor of `B` would naturally lead to the `noexcept` of the move constructor of `D`. Although the result of the compiler conforms to this idea, the standard does Deny it.

Comment: @TedLyngmo I don't think that throwing while evaluating the default argument value for a `noexcept` function means calling `std::terminate`. My understanding is that the default value is evaluated outside of the context of the function, it basically replaces the argument at the call site. If you have `void foo(int) noexcept` and `int bar()` then if you try `foo(bar())` and `bar` throws, the `foo` function did not throw so there is no need for `std::terminate`. It seems to me like this is the same situation.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux If that's the case, I'm even more confused :-) The `try / catch` in my example at the top catches the exception if we declare the move constructor `noexcept(false)` but calls `std::terminate` if we make the move constructor `noexcept(true)`.

Comment: @TedLyngmo That's because your example uses `D` which seems to have a `noexcept` move constructor (which is the basis of this question) and in that case the default argument is evaluated in a `noexcept` context (the context is `D::D(D&&) noexcept`). If you use `B` instead you will get `"throw"` as an output even when `B(B&&)` is `noexcept` because the default argument is not evaluated in a `noexcept` context (the context is `int main()` which is not `noexcept`).

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux (facepalm) Doh... Thanks again. I think I need a break :-D

Comment: «implicitly invokes» means only subexpressions of _E_, not bodies of functions which may be invoked during _E_ evaluation

Comment: @LanguageLawyer So is the call of `D`'s move constructor to `B`'s move constructor an "implicitly invoke"?

Comment: Call to a base move constructor happens inside the body of a derived class

Comment: @LanguageLawyer But how to understand the examples in the standard I quoted? The standard stipulates that `D::D(D&&)` should be potentially-throwing. And I also discussed that `D::D(D&&)` is not affected by the destructor of `B` and `D`.

Answer (score 2):

I would argue that the following code comment in the non-normative example of [[except.spec]/12](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/except.spec#12) is inaccurate, at best.

> D​::​D(D&&) potentially-throwing, as the default argument for B's constructor may throw

`D​::​D(D&&)` is potentially throwing in the [except.spec]/12 example because its destructor is throwing, not because of the default argument for `B`.

If we return to OP's example (no throwing dtor), for `D::D(D&&)` to be potentially-throwing, it should fulfill [[except.spec]/7](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/except.spec#7):

> **An implicitly-declared constructor for a class `X`**, or a
> constructor without a noexcept-specifier that is defaulted on its
> first declaration, **has a potentially-throwing exception specification
> if and only if any of the following constructs is
> potentially-throwing:**
>
> - (7.1) a constructor selected by overload resolution in the implicit definition of the constructor for class `X` to initialize a
>   potentially constructed subobject, or
> - (7.2) **a subexpression of such an initialization**, such as a default argument expression, or,
> - (7.3) for a default constructor, a default member initializer.

(7.1) does not apply: the subobject is of type `B` and the viable constructor is `B(B&&, int = (throw 0, 0)) noexcept` which, as a construct (not an expression) is declared to be noexcept, and does thus not have a potentially-throwing exception specification.

(7.3) does not apply.

Thus, (7.2) remains, and applies only if `throw 0` is a subexpression of an initialization using the `D​::​D(D&&)` constructor.

A subexpression is as per [[intro.execution]/4](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/intro.execution#4):

> A subexpression of an expression E is an immediate subexpression of E or a subexpression of an immediate subexpression of E.

and, as already listed by OP, an immediate subexpressions is specified by [[intro.execution]/3](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/intro.execution#3):

> The immediate subexpressions of an expression E are
>
> - (3.1) the constituent expressions of E's operands ([expr.prop]),
> - (3.2) **any function call that E implicitly invokes,**
> - (3.3) if E is a lambda-expression, the initialization of the entities captured by copy and the constituent expressions of the
>   initializer of the init-captures,
> - (3.4) if E is a function call or implicitly invokes a function, the constituent expressions of each default argument ([dcl.fct.default])
>   used in the call, or
> - (3.5) if E creates an aggregate object ([dcl.init.aggr]), the constituent expressions of each default member initializer
>   ([class.mem]) used in the initialization.

I have not been able to find a formal specification of what "*implicitly* invokes" means, but based on [[class.copy.ctor]/14](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/class.copy.ctor#14.sentence-1):

> The implicitly-defined copy/move constructor for a non-union class X **performs a memberwise** copy/**move of its bases** and members. [...]

the implicitly-defined move ctor performs e.g. the move of its bases explicitly (just as a user-provided ctor definition would). Thus, I would argue that invocation of `D::D(&&)` does not *implicitly* invoke `B(B&&, int = (throw 0, 0)) noexcept`, thus short-circuiting the subexpression recursion before reaching the throwing default argument of `B`'s move constructor. Meaning `D::D(&&)` does not have a potentially-throwing exception specification.

Comment: I'd say "such an initialization" refers to an initialization described by 7.1; that's the part that mentions initialization; `D(D&&)` is referred to as "implicitly-declared constructor for a class X", not in terms of an initialization. Which means that 7.2 is also talking about the initialization of potentially constructed subobjects, so the question is whether `throw 0` is a subexpression of the invocation of `B`'s constructor using the default argument, and the answer to that is, as far as I can tell, yes.

Comment: "`D​::​D(D&&)` is potentially throwing in the [except.spec]/12 example because its destructor is throwing": "its destructor", as in, `D::~D()`? As far as I understand, a potentially-throwing destructor doesn't make a constructor of the class potentially-throwing (an expression that creates a temporary of that type could be potentially-throwing, but that's different). If "its destructor" refers to `B::~B()`, then see Note 2 on paragraph 7 - that doesn't make `D​::​D(D&&)` potentially-throwing either. Also, note that `D::D(const D&)` is non-throwing, although the same destructors are involved.

Comment: Yes, I am also confused about the concept of "implicitly invoke". But I also think Bodgan's comment is reasonable. For the example in the standard, if the move constructor of `D` is affected by the destructor, why is the copy constructor of `D` not affected? Does this mean that `D`'s move constructor is indeed affected by `B`'s move constructor? But the standard expects `D`'s move constructor to be potentially-throwing, which is different from the result of the compiler.